# Firebase realtime database no longer loading in my console. Writes also failed inside my Android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase realtime database is no longer loading in my console. It only show an empty content without any error. Rules for the database fail to load as well.
Inside my Android app writes to the realtime database fail with :

```
E/SOL: failed to put
'https://[appid].firebaseio.com/logs/2022/3/12/0/us_0600830214/s110.json',
ex: Failed to connect to
[appid].firebaseio.com/2600:1901:0:94b6:::443
     java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to
[appid].firebaseio.com/2600:1901:0:94b6:::443
 atokhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.kt:297)
 atokhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:207)
 atokhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226)
 atokhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106)
 atokhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74)
 atokhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255)
 atokhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
 atokhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
 atokhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
 atokhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
 atokhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
 atokhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
 atokhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
 atokhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
 atokhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
 atokhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
 atjava.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
 atjava.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
         Suppressed: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect
to [appid].firebaseio.com/35.201.97.85 (port 443) from
/10.0.2.16 (port 33500) after 10000ms
         at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:191)
         at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:135)
         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
 atjava.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
 atjava.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
 atjava.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
         at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
         at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
 atokhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.kt:120)
 atokhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.kt:295)
```

I changed nothing in my code or console. A couple of days ago the console stop loading and the write errors I think stop working way before I just didn't pay much attention to it.

I don't see any project quotas being surpassed, all values are very close to 0% of usage for the free spark plan.

I also checked the google-services.json, minor changes, ... and updating to the new version did not fix the write failures.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Are you saying that the database also doesn't load for you in the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/)? If so, since the ones I just tested load fine, it is unlikely that we can help you here. I recommend that you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

I have contacted Firebase support and they have confirmed that such behavior have been reported by several other users but from what they can tell it is all fine on their side. The issue lies with the ISP from my country. All other reports had the same origin.